# SQL Server 2012 using MSA -- SharePoint 2010 Powershell backups impossible?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble trying to do a simple backup of our 2-server SharePoint 2010 farm. I'm running the backup process with a Powershell command, backing up to a UNC shared folder on the SharePoint server.

I have SP2010 on one server and SQL 2012 on another. SQLserver.exe is being run by a new Managed Service Account. I have put this account into a new group and then I gave that group read/write permissions on the backup share at both the Share and Filesystem level.

My farm account also has read/write access to the backup folder. I'm starting my backup process via Administrator account.

My backup commands:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
Backup-SPFarm -Directory \\SHAREPOINT\Backup\Sharepoint -BackupMethod full
```

The error I'm seeing:

```
[8/13/2012 12:07:01 PM] Warning: [SharePoint_Config] Cannot open backup device '\\SHAREPOINT\Backup\Sharepoint\spbr0001\000000C6.bak'. Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I'm thinking that for some reason MSAs aren't supported with this backup method but I can't find any information on this anywhere. SharePoint 2010 doesn't support using MSAs for running the services but SQL 2012 does.

I am unable to use the MSA as a login account to be able to check if it can access the UNC from the SQL Server properly like I would a normal account.

Comment: After changing SQLserver.exe to run as a normal domain account, also a member of the group with write access to the UNC backup share, it appears to be working.

Comment: I still don't understand why a MSA can't be used to run SQL *and* backup SharePoint.

Comment: Well, it looks like it works after-all. Maybe I just needed to reboot the SharePoint machine??? Weird...

Comment: Could also be an access denied if the same account's trying to access the same network resource from more than one location (such as would happen if the same MSA was being used to run SQL and your script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some sort of permissions mis-setup on the network share of the folder.  Did you create the group that the MSA is in on the SharePoint server, the SQL Server or within AD?

What permissions did you give to the group on the folder and the SharePoint server?

Comment: Created the group in AD. First it only had the MSA that SQLServer.exe used as a member. The group is read/write on both the backup share and the folder. I created a new AD service account (normal user) started SQLserver.exe with this user, and added the user to the aformentioned group. Restarted SharePoint services, ran the backup and all is good now.

Comment: That's strange.  The MSA should have worked.  I'd assume that Kerberos isn't working correctly on the domain or SQL isn't talking to the domain correctly over Kerberos.  There should be some useful information in the security log on the sharepoint server.

Comment: You are correct, I do not have Kerberos setup. Maybe that is the problem? It's a simple site with the domain primarily supporting this SharePoint app so I didn't bother. Thanks for looking. I will take a look at the logs. :-)

Comment: Well, I have no idea what I did, but when I changed SQLServer back to using the MSA again, then restarted the SharePoint server, the backup works with 0 errors.

Comment: Did you remember to restart the SQL Service?

Comment: Yes, SQL Configuration Manager restarts it for you. :-)

Comment: OK, just checking as you didn't specify. :)